# Why have citric acid only a denticity of 3 and tartaric acid of only 2?

Tags: coordination-compounds, amines

Why can't the hydroxyl-groups in citric acid (denticity 3)

[image]

or in tartaric acid (denticity 2)

[image]

contribute to the denticity, as there are doing it in aminoethylethanolamine (denticity 3)

[image]

Why do the hydroxyl-groups can't contribute in the first two compounds?

Comment: Their denticity can get up to 4, maybe even higher, just not with only one cation, because of steric reasons.

Comment: So, the molecule itself gets in the way?

Comment: This sort of thing is where you need a good 3D model kit to play around. It really helps.